# Powershell remote backup monitoring issue

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have put together a script to check around my servers on the Backup using get-wbsummary.

Some reason the session is not really working and I am loosing this, could someone give me a hint where did I go wrong?

Thank you in advance for all the comments, if you feel that there is a better solution please don't hesitate to share, I am here to learn too.

```
 $serverlist=@(“bla”,“bla”,“bla”)

$command={$lastback = get-wbsummary | Select-object -property lastsuccessfulbackup}

$lastdate=@()
foreach ($svrs in $serverlist) {
  $sess=Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $svrs
  Invoke-command -session $sess -ScriptBlock $command
  remove-pssession -session $sess

  $object=New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   Severname=$svrs;
   Lastbackup=$lastback
  }
 $lastdate+=$object
}
```

Error message is:
Invoke-Command: cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session' because it is null.

EDIT:

With some help - thank you @Eris - please find the working code below for others to look at it:

```
 $serverlist=@(“bla”,“bla”,“bla”)

$command={get-wbsummary | Select-object -property lastsuccessfulbackuptime, currentoperationstatus}
$lastdate=@()

foreach ($svrs in $serverlist) {
  $sess=New-PSSession -ComputerName $svrs

  $lastback=Invoke-command -session $sess -ScriptBlock $command
 remove-pssession -session $sess
  $object=New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   Severname=$svrs;
   Lastbackup=$lastback.lastsuccessfulbackuptime;
   Progress=$lastback.currentoperationstatus;
  }
 $lastdate+=$object
}
$lastdate
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `New-PSSession` instead of `Enter-PSSession` ? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847839.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much that was the problem, never mind the code from other aspect is still wrong:) but I have figured it out that.

Comment: the Invoke-command would not pass back the data so if it is stored in a string that is a better chance to catch is:)